# Are managed databases (e.g. Amazon RDS) slower to access than databases on the same machine (EC2) as the web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds

Imagine two cases:

1. I have web server running in an EC2 instance and it is connected to the database in the RDS, the managed database service.
2. I have web server and database running in the same EC2 instance.

Is my database in RDS going to be slower to access because it's not in the same machine?

How many milliseconds, approximately, does it add to your latency between the two?

Does this become bottleneck?

What about other managed database services like Azure, GCP, Digital Ocean, etc?
Do they behave the same?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will be slower to RDS instances from your Webserver than a database on the **same** host, because you need to go over the network and that adds latency.

The drawback of running the DB on the same server is that you can't use a managed service to take care of your database and you're mixing largely stateless components (webserver) with stateful components (database). This solution is typically not scalable either. If you add more webservers, things get messy.

Don't know about Azure, GCP or Digital Ocean, but I'd be very surprised if things are different there. There's good reasons to separate these components.

Comment: How significant is this increase in latency? Because one thing we all software developers hate is slowness in our app.

Comment: Well, you have to measure it :D - Typically that adds a couple of milliseconds and since every major website is built that way I'd expect this not to be a problem. Usually bottlenecks are elsewhere.

Comment: @abcDE chances are the query you perform, the choosen database, the created indices, the amount of data to select, the technology in the webserver, the coding of your app, etc.  all have vastly more impact on any latency than the ec2 -> rds connection.